# What is the easiest one click install method for PostGIS and it's entire dependencies?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, apache

For someone new to database servers and their dependencies, what is the easiest assured way of installing PostGIS on a machine with no other software beyond what comes with its operating system? I'd like to know for Ubuntu, Windows and if possible a common Linux method. I'm understanding that you need to install PostGreSQL first, but before that perhaps you need to install Apache Server, and I'm not sure if that has dependencies.

Perhaps there a single binary that loads EVERYTHING for Windows, and maybe there a single program from the Ubuntu GIS repositories that installs everything. If not, what's the install order?

Comment: Postgis doesn't need for Apache.

Answer (score 6):

I have found for windows users using the Enterprise Postgres Installers with
**StackBuilder** the easiest way to get up and running from a clean install (no previous versions of database etc.)

The PostgreSQL installers include the database server, pgAdmin and StackBuilder.

Notes:
**Internet Connection is required during the install as downloads items based on users input.

Versions 9.0, 9.1 and 9.2 below have been updated to incorporate the security patches released on Thursday, April 4th, 2013.

Download from:

http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload

Installation Guide available:

http://www.enterprisedb.com/resources-community/pginst-guide

Answer (score 4):

**For Ubuntu**

```
sudo apt_get install postgresql postgis postgresql-9.1-postgis

sudo -i -u postgres
createdb postgis
psql -d postgis -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/contrib/postgis-1.5/postgis.sql
psql -d postgis -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/contrib/postgis-1.5/spatial_ref_sys.sql
psql -d postgis -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/contrib/postgis_comments.sql
```

Comment: Is `CREATE EXTENSION postgis` only for PostGis 2.0?

Comment: Nop. `CREATE EXTENSION`, is for PostgreSQL 9.x :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way (at least in Windows):

You can use, use [EnterpriseDB installer](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#windows) (windows & linux), once you had installed PostgreSQL, use "StackBuilder" utility to install PostGIS optional library (PostGIS recommends this method in his web site)

Then you need to install pgAdminIII to connect to PostgreSQL.