# Loading Features prompt in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, performance, fields-attributes

I'm currently working on a dataset with 3.8m records. I have a very simple expression to update a field that I want to execute using the Field Calculator, while having the Attribute Table open.

Do I need to wait for the Loading Features prompt to complete for every Field Calculator operation? This is very slow on my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, you would need to wait for the edits to complete before you can save them. You could follow some helpful advice as mentioned in the following post:

[mapping over a million points using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173136/mapping-over-a-million-points-using-qgis)

Such as:

- Deleting unneccessary fields (which will initially take time but will speed things up eventually)
- Import your data as a database in [PostGIS](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/spatial_databases/index.html). (recommended when working with shedloads of data)

Comment: I've already looked at cutting down the size of fields, and the number of fields in the attribute table. It still takes a long time. I will look into PostGIS, hopefully that helps out.